# Select column name only from table in stored procedure

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

I want to extract only column from stored procedure. I have tried it but it won't work.

This is my code:

```
create procedure [dbo].[sample]
    @mc as varchar(5)
as
begin
    select @mc  
    from Layout;
end
```

Table structure `dbo.layout`:

```
layout_id = 1, mc1 = 5, mc2 = 6, mc3 = 8, m4 = 10
```

eg to do:

```
select mcX from layout;
```

via stored procedure.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Remove @ only use select mc from Layout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to use dynamic SQL to specify the column to return:

```
create procedure [dbo].[sample]

@mc as nvarchar(5)

as
begin
    declare @sql nvarchar(100) = N'select ' +  QUOTENAME(@mc) + N' from Layout'

    exec sp_executesql @sql
end
```